# Yeoman using NodeGit's Reset, getting constant object error

Tags: node.js, yeoman, nodegit

First time using [NodeGit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit) and having issues with the [Reset](http://www.nodegit.org/api/reset/) function.

I'm trying to reset a folder that has been cloned to the current HEAD of origin/master.

Even though i'm giving it a target, it says it's still required:

```
Error: Object target is required.
```

Current code:

```
var Reset = nodegit.Reset;
var templateDir = this.templatePath('/folder');

nodegit.Repository.open(templateDir)
    .then(function(repo) {
        repository = repo;

        Reset.reset(repository, templateDir, Reset.TYPE.HARD, {
            remoteCallbacks: {
                credentials: function(url, userName) {
                    return nodegit.Cred.sshKeyNew(userName, sshPublicKey, sshPrivateKey, "");
                }
            }
        })
        .done(function(repo) {
            console.log("reset done");
        });
    });
```

templateDir is the full path to the folder using Yeoman's templatePath.

Wondering if anyone can give me insight into what i'm doing wrong or missing. I didn't see an example for this in their Example folder.

My expected end result would be equal to running this in terminal:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [test case](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/test/tests/reset.js#L184) that does a hard reset for an example.

The gist is that `templateDir` is the commit object that you want to reset to. You don't really need `remoteCallbacks` either unless you want to do a fetch or some sort of remote operation.

Try this:

```
var Reset = nodegit.Reset;
var templateDir = this.templatePath('/folder');
var repository = repo;

nodegit.Repository.open(templateDir)
.then(function(repo) {
    repository = repo;

    return repository.fetch('origin');
})
.then(function() {
    return repository.getBranchCommit('origin/HEAD');
})
.then(function(originHeadCommit) {
    return Reset.reset(repository, originHeadCommit, Reset.TYPE.HARD);
})
.done(function(repo) {
    console.log("reset done");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i'm getting a `Error: Reference 'refs/remotes/origin/HEAD' not found` when running the above. So getBranchCommit isn't finding the remote head, any advice?

Comment: I just added a fetch to the example. Give that a try.

Comment: I think we're getting close. Here is what i'm working with now:  https://gist.github.com/7674b50839b4e11c23b3 - It's not throwing any errors now but it's also not reseting the files.

Comment: Also, if I change the getBranchCommit to `origin` it gives the same error as my first comment.

Comment: Sorry, just now getting back into this. I figured out my issue with the above running but not reseting the repo. I just had to change `getBranchCommit('origin');` to `getBranchCommit('origin/master');`. It was essentially looking at my local repo's head instead of the remote. 

My final code ended up like this  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4cca3669d82853ce79b1